# Create an index table for all tables in a database

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm asking if its possible to have a database->index table-> tables?

I know that we AI the ids inside the table... but lets say we have:

```
1 database => 'books'
5 tables=> 'genre' like
a. fantasy
b. scifi
c. action
d. mystery
e. horror.
```

Each table contains ID, book_name, price of a specific genre.
the index table i want to contain:

```
table_id, 
table_name, 
table_comments (its the same we do with data but now we do it for tables)
```

Also this index_table should auto update whenever a table is dropped or created. Now is it possible?

Comment: Your have a poor data structure.  The five tables should be one table with a column specifying the genre.

Comment: yes i know but its a simple example with minimalistic features to be easy,  to understand

Comment: Why not use the structures exposed by the RDBMS itself? Like dba_tables for oracle...

Comment: No, the 'simple example' cannot be given an 'index table'.

Comment: ok so you are saying that its possible! can you give us an example then with an index table??

Comment: You're going to have to come up with a better example that shows why this would be necessary. In your example, it's far better to create a single table with a genre attribute. Don't overcomplicate things.